# Change a value to true on liquid Shopify overlay header

Tags: templates, header, shopify, overlay, liquid

I'm trying to set the overlay header on some pages where the overlay header is not a standard setting on my Motion theme of my Shopify store.

This is the store link: https://hatproof.com/

I premise that I'm not very good on liquid code, and I'm asking here for help.

This are the original code lines:

```
assign template_name = template | replace: '.', ' ' | truncatewords: 2, '' | handle
assign sticky_header = false
  assign overlay_header = false

  if section.settings.header_sticky
    assign sticky_header = true
  endif

  if template_name == 'index' and section.settings.sticky_index
    assign overlay_header = true
  endif
  if template_name == 'collection' and collection.image and section.settings.sticky_collection
    assign overlay_header = true
  endif
```

I've try to edit adding this on the bottom:

```
if template_name == 'page.chisiamo'
    assign overlay_header = true
  endif
```

But the "overlay_header" value of the page https://hatproof.com/pages/nuovo-chi-siamo ('page.chisiamo' template name) hasn't changed to "true".

I've also try to edit the variable name in 'page', 'page chisiamo' but never worked.

This is how the value is used:

```
<div data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="header">
  <div id="HeaderWrapper" class="header-wrapper{% if overlay_header %} header-wrapper--overlay is-light{% endif %}">
```

What can I do to change the "overlay_header" value to true of some specific pages?

Comment: use if `template_name == 'chisiamo'` instead of `if template_name == 'page.chisiamo'`

Comment: I've try to edit like this and don't work :(

Comment: are you able to share the code snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the **template_name** variable you have filter replace a dot with an interval and after that handle filter.

After that interaction the **page.chisiamo** no longer be like the template string.

You transform it at first to **page chisiamo** with the replace,
after to **page-chisiamo** with handle filter.

You can use this:

```
{%- if template_name == 'page-chisiamo' -%}
   {%- assign overlay_header = true -%}
{%-endif -%}
```

Or you can just check if the template_name contains the chisiamo, like this:

```
{%- if template_name contains 'chisiamo' -%}
   {%- assign overlay_header = true -%}
{%-endif -%}
```

Comment: @imones; Please accept @kamenarov 's answer by clicking the 'tick' mark!